# break line in alert with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
<?php
function alert($msg) 
{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msg');</script>";
}
if(array_key_exists('btnRegisterAdmins', $_POST)) 
{ 
$fname = $_POST['FirstName'];
$lname=$_POST['LastName'];


if(empty($fname))
{
    $alertscript = "you need...<br />";
}
if(empty($lname))
{
    $alertscript = $alertscript  . "<br /> to be good...";
    alert($alertscript);
}
?>
```

The output was without a line drop
and the tag itself appears.
Which way can i solve this?

Comment: Please use a code formatter when posting code. Also there is a missing '}' after your first if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<br />` is html. Try `\n` instead of the `<br />` tag.

Comment: But it is..   https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_alert2

Answer (score 1):

```js
alert(" hi \r\n i am at new line")
```

second occurance of `<br/>` in your code is replaced with "/r"
Try

```
<?php
function alert($msg) 
{

$msg = "'$msg'";  //to get message enclosed by single quotes
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>",  //try other approach
     "alert($msg);",
     "</script>";
}

$arr = array("btnRegisterAdmins"=>1);


if(array_key_exists('btnRegisterAdmins', $arr)) 
{

    $fname = "";  //guessing no fname
    $lname="";  //guessing no lname

    $alertscript ="";

    if(empty($fname))
    {
        $alertscript = " you need...";

    }

    if(empty($lname))
    {   
        $alertscript = $alertscript  . '\r to be good...';
        alert($alertscript);

    }



}
?>
```